# Since both 'getFragmentManager()' and 'android.preference.PreferenceFragment' are deprecated, how can I alternate my code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Since in API level 28 both `'getFragmentManager()'` and `'android.preference.PreferenceFragment'` are deprecated, how can I implement some alternatives to my code without losing functionalities.

I read in a similar post that the first problem could be solved by using FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Also, for the second problem with PreferenceFragment I haven't really seen any suggestions and thus don't know what to change it with.

**Here is my SettingsActivity class:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

}

Here is a printscreen of it:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyAIG.jpg

Comment: Use the AndroidX implementation of fragments (`androidx.app.Fragment)` or the Android Support Library implementation of fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). For preferences, use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` matching your fragment implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the new support libraries :

Use `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` with  `androidx.app.Fragment` support library instead.

and `PreferenceFragmentCompat()` with `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-alpha3`

Comment: And how do I implement `androidx.app.Fragment` and `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-alpha3`? 

Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm pretty new at this

Comment: Add them to your app gradle dependencies

Comment: Could you maybe tell me exactly which two lines to put in dependencies?

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Comment: yeah, still can't seem to find it...sorry to bother you but could you give it a look?

Comment: You have to add it this way :
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-alpha3' in your app gradle in dependencies

Comment: Who uses `FragmentActivity`?